# Anchor while itering - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration, anchor

I am trying to make an anchor in an index page while itering through a list of elements.
On the home page I display each element with a 'more info' button. When clicked it goes to the index of detailed elements. I tried the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
link_to 'More info', tours_path(@tour, :anchor => "#{tour.name}"
```

I also tried, without success:

```
link_to 'More info', tours_path(@tour, :anchor => tour.name
```

Here is the code of home.html.erb :

```
<section id="walking-tours">
  <h2 class="text-center">Lisbon walking tours </h2>
      <div class="walking-tours d-flex">
        <% @tours.each do |tour| %>
          <div class="walking-tours-cards item">
            <% photo = tour.photos[0] %>
             <%= cl_image_tag photo.key, height: 300, width: 300, crop: :fill if tour.photos.attached? %>
                <h3> <%= tour.name  %> </h3>
                <p> <%= tour.description %> </p>
                 <%= link_to 'More info', tours_path(@tour, :anchor => "#{tour.name}"), class: 'btn btn-outline-secondary' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
</section>
```

and the code in index.html.erb

```
<div class="index-tours">
  <div class="tours-title">
    <h1 >WALKING TOURS</h1>
  </div>

     <div class="tours-list">
        <% @tours.each do |tour| %>
         <div class="walking-tours-details ">

          <div class="walking-tours-info">
            <h3> <%= tour.name  %> </h3>
            <p> <%= tour.full_information %> </p>
            <p><b>Duration</b> -<%= tour.duration %> </p>
            <p><b>Meeting Point</b> - <%= tour.meeting_point %> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="tours-pics">
            <% tour.photos.each do |photo| %>
             <%= cl_image_tag photo.key, height: 220, width: 220, crop: :fill, :class => "tours-img" %>
            <% end %>
          </div>

          </div>
            <% if logged_in? %>
              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tour_path(tour), :class => "tours-links" %> <%= link_to 'Destroy', tour, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

For now, all 'more info' buttons go to the first element of the list (at the top of the index page).
Any idea to help? Thanks!!
Cécile

Comment: What code does it generate? As a note, your second form is the recommended one as 99% of the time `"#{x}"` and `x` are identical, excepting cases where you meant `x.to_s` instead.

Comment: One thing that stands out is you're linking to `@tour` with an anchor from `tour`. Shouldn't those both be the same? I'm supposing `@tour` should be `tour`.

Comment: hello tadman, I tried with tour instead of `@tour` but it doesn't work. What is weird is I tried also with `@profile` (which is totally absurd as there is no profile variable in my code) and it doesn't raise any error. The link still work and go to the top of the index page. As for your question 'What code does it generate?' : Not sure what you mean so I can't answer ;(

Comment: As in look at the source in your browser of the page that generates and check that the HTML attributes are set correctly.

Comment: The source loaded corresponds to the name of each tour. And the url seems ok too: `http://localhost:3000/tours.21#The%20Mediterranean%20Civilizations` for one tour and `http://localhost:3000/tours.22#The%20Portuguese%20Tiles` for the other. Is the anchor only working with id or class name? As I iterate through each tour, I can't give them a unique ID or class. I am stuck..

Comment: Make sure you're giving the `anchor:` option to the `tours_path` method and `class:` to `link_to`. It's easy to put these in the wrong spot and then you end up with `?class=class_name` showing up in your link by accident. One thing to note: `tours_path(@tour, :anchor => "#{tour.name}")` should be `tours_path(tour, anchor:  tour.name)` more minimally. Avoid pointless quoting like `"#{x}"`. Also use the `x: y` style of named arguments vs. the very old Ruby 1.8 `:x => y`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by generating a dynamic ID:

```
  <% tour_link = tour.name %>
  <% tour_identification = tour_link.gsub(/\s+/, '') %>
  <div id= <%= tour_identification %> >
```

and for the link_to :

```
<%= link_to 'More info', tours_path(tour, anchor: tour_identification) %>
```

But I still wonder if the anchor could work without an ID.